# Best data structure for 1)Inserting an element 2)Finding minimum element 3)Deleting minimum element

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Best data structure for 
1)Inserting an element 
2)Finding minimum element 
3)Deleting minimum element

Options:

a)Array
b)Stack
c)Queue
d)Linked list
e)Heap.

Explain why

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: Ha Ha.. kind of it..

Answer (score 1):

A min heap has O(log n) for delete min and insert, and O(1) for find min.